Ionic/Angular app working locally but not hosted
i have an ionic app with angular 18 when i run ng serve or ionic serve it works but when i push it to git to deploy on my azure static web app it displays juts the bg same as if i try to build an APK with capacitor
Hosted

Local

This is my angular.config
"projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
          "styleext": "scss",
          "standalone": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": ["src/global.scss", "src/theme/variables.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json",
            "optimization": { "styles": { "inlineCritical": false } }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "serviceWorker": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "8kb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },

Index.html when i open it from www folder is also blank
I have tired changing the base and different build types even asked GPT but nothing

Could you please provide some detail regarding how you're actually deploying to Azure? You're either running into an issue with your Azure StaticWebApp configuration, or, more likely, your deploying something incorrectly -- wrong branch, possibly?

Hi so i am just using the default azure workflow to deploy angular apps from main.


Index.html when i open it from www folder is also blank

This issue typically stems from build configuration problems or runtime errors in the production build.

After building the app (ng build --configuration production), serve the www folder using a simple HTTP server (like http-server) instead of opening index.html directly. Open the app in the browser and press F12 to open Developer Tools.

Angular applications depend on the <base href="/"> tag in index.html to resolve relative URLs. An incorrect base href can lead to resources not loading properly. If the app is hosted in a subdirectory, adjust the base href follow like this<base href="/subdirectory/">).

You have src/manifest.webmanifest listed twice in the assets array. Remove the duplicate to avoid potential conflicts.

"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "assets"
  },
  "src/manifest.webmanifest"
],

In the build options, serviceWorker is set to true, but in the production configuration, it's set to false. This inconsistency might cause issues.
routes.json file:
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}

Sometimes, stale build caches can cause unexpected issues. use this cmd - ng build --configuration production --delete-output-path 

From local, it works perfect!
Result:

After deploying the app to static app service:

